# Tailwind CSS is not working in Vite + React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite

I created a React application using Vite and used the documentation provided here to install Tailwind: [Tailwind CSS Installation Guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite).

However, it's not picking up any of the Tailwind styles.

**tailwind.config.cjs**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**index.css**

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**main.tsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./router";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The only dependency I have installed is `react-router-dom`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

If you have installed postcss and autoprefixer (as outlined in step #2 here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite), you should see both libraries in the "devDependencies" section of your `package.json`. If they are installed, you will need a `postcss.config.cjs` file in the root of your project which contains the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I had all three libraries installed in devDependecies, postcss.config.cjs was not there, it helped. But it's not mentioned in the documentation. And thanks for correcting the question grammatically.

Answer (score 6):

After following the guides from the official [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), you may want to check in your package.json file and see under the devDependencies if tailwind is appearing there or not. Also, check in your postcss.config.cjs file and see if the following is there:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, posts.config.cjs was not there, it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the Changes I made in `vite.config.js` and it worked

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Bless you for coming back and posting the solution. I was missing `tailwind()` in my plugins. <3

Comment: Holy god, why isn't this mentioned in the tailwind documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the `index.css` file is imported. In my situation, I accidentally removed the `import "./index.css"` line in `main.jsx` while deleting some boilerplate code.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css"; // Make sure this line is not removed
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you need to run this command line below, to generate tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js files inside the root of your project, rerun your app and should be fixed.
visit: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Your postcss.config.js file is missing.
Run command `npx tailwindcss init -p`
This will create postcss.config.js file with the following code

```
export default {
plugins: {
tailwindcss: {},
autoprefixer: {},},}
```